# how to retrieve a record always first and rest of the records using orderby?

Tags: sql, eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-4.2

I am new to Laravel.
I am trying to retrieve some records from a database. I need one of the row to be always in the first place, and rest in alphabetical order.Like this :

```
CategoryID     Category
---------------------------
54            New Products
1             Amino Acids
3             b---
34            c----
4             d---
```

How should I rewrite my code to achieve this?

```
$db_categories = Category::get();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```php
Category::orderBy(DB::raw("IF(category = 'New Products', 0, 1), Category"))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't know why, It is not working for me.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Database is MySql

Comment: I tested the code with your sample data and it worked for me. Can you replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and post the result?

Comment: I replaced get() with toSql()
and there is an error ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I meant like this: `dd(Category::orderBy(DB::raw("..."))->toSql());`

Comment: string(86) "select * from `tblcategory` order by IF(category = 'New Products', 0, 1), Category asc"
this is what I got

Comment: Actually, this is working when I use this query in phpMyAdmin. But doesn't work in browser. I need to find out the reason.

Comment: Is the order also incorrect in `dd(Category::orderBy(DB::raw("..."))->get());`?

Comment: Looks like your code somehow changes the order after that.

Comment: Yea.. I just commented the below code and finally, it is working for me. 

    if (is_array($categories[$cat->CategoryTypeID]['categories'])) {
                usort($categories[$cat->CategoryTypeID]['categories'], function ($a, $b) {
                    $a_norm = str_replace(['É', 'é'], ['E', 'e'], $a['name']);
                    $b_norm = str_replace(['É', 'é'], ['E', 'e'], $b['name']);
                
                    return strcasecmp($a_norm, $b_norm);
                });
            }

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Laravel, but - as you tagged the question with SQL-ish tags, here you go: use CASE (or similar function, available in the database you use; such as DECODE in Oracle). For example:

- I want to have DEPTNO = 30 (department number) first
- the rest should be sorted by DNAME (department name), alphabetically

---

```
SQL> select * from dept
  2  order by case when deptno = 30 then 1
  3                else 2
  4           end,
  5           dname;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS

SQL>
```

Hopefully, you'll be able to use something like that in your case.

Comment: I am not sure how to use this in Laravel. Anyway, Thank you so much for helping.